# How to obtain string out of IObservable<string> Reactive Extensions

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I have a method that returns IObservable

```
private IObservable<String> Name() {}
```

I want to obtain a regular string after calling that method such as

```
string name = Name(). ???
```

What do I use instead of the ???

Comment: Have you tried using intellisense to see what is available after the dot ?

Comment: After that, you can look at the MSDN documentation on Observable

Comment: You are trying to "pull" the name from the observable.  That is literally the exact opposite of how reactive extensions are intended to be used.

Comment: @KirkWoll Then it's probably a good idea to share how they should be used. Otherwise, they may simply ignore that statement, and continue to make the same mistakes. (Just saying ;) )

Comment: I think this question is useful as it stands. The sarcastic commentary isn't helpful, and Rx can be a pretty overwhelming topic to break into. Reopen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
string name = Name().Wait();
```

... which will block. Not really in the spirit of Rx though. It's better to Subscribe to it with a delegate that will be called when the result is available:

```
Name().Subscribe(name => /* Do something with name */);
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a few of ways to do this.

First, you could just `Wait`, as James suggested. However, this has the potential of entering a dead-lock, depending on the implementation of the Name observable and the environment in which you are running your code.

```
string name = Name().Wait();
```

Or, you could set it as a side-effect of your subscription. This is better, but it begs the questions, "What if I need it synchronously?"

```
string name = null;
Name().Subscribe(x => name = x);
```

If you have access to the TPL, you also have some options with `async`.

```
public async Task DoThing() {
    string name = await Name(); // or await Name().FirstOrDefaultAsync();
};
```

So, if you need to synchronize to a non-reactively, you could use the TPL and `async` / `await`. If you need to perform a side-effect which uses the name, you could use `Do` or `Subscribe`, and if you understand how `Wait` works, you could retrieve the name in a purely synchronous environment.

To understand which is best for you, I think we'd all need to see a bit more code. Basically, how are you going to use the name? That's extremely important to understanding how you should use the observable.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
string name = await Name();
```

Or:

```
string name = Name.First();
```

If you're into the whole synchronicity thing.